# On vpn connection I'm getting "Linux route add command failed", but I'm not pushing any routes on server.conf

Tags: linux, routing, openvpn, ubuntu-16.04

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 server. I configured 2 clients and server. The goal is to connect those two clients to the server and ssh from one to another. I can connect on Linux Mint, adding vpn connection by right clicking on internet connection icon and specifying .ovpn file.
Unfortunately, I can't connect with the same server and the second similar client configuration on Raspberry Pi Stretch using:

```
sudo openvpn --config client2.ovpn
```

I'm getting

```
ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
```

Full response:

```
Wed Nov 20 11:33:49 2019 OpenVPN 2.4.7 arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Feb 20 2019
Wed Nov 20 11:33:49 2019 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019, LZO 2.10
Wed Nov 20 11:33:49 2019 NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Wed Nov 20 11:33:50 2019 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Wed Nov 20 11:33:50 2019 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Wed Nov 20 11:33:50 2019 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]51.75.127.237:1194
Wed Nov 20 11:33:50 2019 Socket Buffers: R=[163840->163840] S=[163840->163840]
Wed Nov 20 11:33:50 2019 UDP link local: (not bound)
Wed Nov 20 11:33:50 2019 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]xx.xx.xx.xx:1194
Wed Nov 20 11:33:50 2019 NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
Wed Nov 20 11:33:50 2019 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]xx.xx.xx.xx:1194, sid=bd06e3d1 f7c41b7e
Wed Nov 20 11:33:50 2019 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=PL, ST=PDK, L=X, O=K, OU=K, CN=K CA, name=server, emailAddress=some_email
Wed Nov 20 11:33:50 2019 VERIFY KU OK
Wed Nov 20 11:33:50 2019 Validating certificate extended key usage
Wed Nov 20 11:33:50 2019 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
Wed Nov 20 11:33:50 2019 VERIFY EKU OK
Wed Nov 20 11:33:50 2019 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=PL, ST=PDK, L=X, O=K, OU=K, CN=K CA, name=server, emailAddress=some_email
Wed Nov 20 11:33:50 2019 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
Wed Nov 20 11:33:50 2019 [server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]xx.xx.xx.xx:1194
Wed Nov 20 11:33:51 2019 SENT CONTROL [server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Wed Nov 20 11:33:51 2019 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0,topology net30,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.8.0.10 10.8.0.9'
Wed Nov 20 11:33:51 2019 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Wed Nov 20 11:33:51 2019 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Wed Nov 20 11:33:51 2019 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Wed Nov 20 11:33:51 2019 Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Wed Nov 20 11:33:51 2019 Outgoing Data Channel: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Wed Nov 20 11:33:51 2019 Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Wed Nov 20 11:33:51 2019 Incoming Data Channel: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Wed Nov 20 11:33:51 2019 ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.8.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=eth1 HWADDR=0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64
Wed Nov 20 11:33:51 2019 TUN/TAP device tun1 opened
Wed Nov 20 11:33:51 2019 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Wed Nov 20 11:33:51 2019 /sbin/ip link set dev tun1 up mtu 1500
Wed Nov 20 11:33:51 2019 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun1 local 10.8.0.10 peer 10.8.0.9
Wed Nov 20 11:33:51 2019 /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf tun1 1500 1570 10.8.0.10 10.8.0.9 init
Wed Nov 20 11:33:51 2019 /sbin/ip route add 10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.9
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Wed Nov 20 11:33:51 2019 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
Wed Nov 20 11:33:51 2019 GID set to nogroup
Wed Nov 20 11:33:51 2019 UID set to nobody
Wed Nov 20 11:33:51 2019 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Wed Nov 20 11:33:51 2019 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

My server.conf:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
key-direction 0
cipher AES-128-CBC   # AES
auth  SHA256
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

my client.ovpn:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote xx.xx.xx.xx 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA256
key-direction 1
comp-lzo
verb3
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
<ca>
...
</ca>
<cert>
...
</cert>
<key>
...
</key>
<tls-auth>
...
</tls-auth>
```

Many thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pushing a route, the route to your OpenVPN gateway (and/or subnet):

`/sbin/ip route add 10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.9`
is being called, your error stems from you already having a route to that host or subnet. Check your active routes on the client (e.g. `ip r`) to confirm.

You also shouldn't use LZO compression with encryption because of [VORACLE](https://openvpn.net/security-advisory/the-voracle-attack-vulnerability/)

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thank you so much. I've changed the address on server.conf to 10.8.1.0 and it worked. I've also commented out LZO on both clients and server, as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the error `RTNETLINK answers: File exists` happens when OpenVPN client is trying to add a route that already exists on the client machine. Then, OpenVPN will generate an error message:

> ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2

Can you check this client machine network settings to ensure that you don't have any route to `10.8.0.0/24` network?